# how to take steps and limits to input time in html5?

Tags: javascript, html, input, time

I need to customize the data entry from `7 to 23 hours` and take `10 minute` steps in the `input time` like the following example:

```
input time >>>
07:10
07:20
07:30
...
...
22:40
22:50
23:00
```

please, help me...

Comment: you need to add `step="600"` attribute of time input for 10 minutes.

Comment: and the limits, please?

Comment: For limits you can use `min` & `max` attributes

Comment: check : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use below attributes :

- `step` for the steps
- `min` for the lower limits
- `max` for upper limits

Check the below code :

```html
<input type="time" step="600" min="07:00" max="23:00" />
```

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time

Comment: Does this work? when i run the code sinppet it shows the mintues steps as 1,2,3... or is there some compatability issue with my browser. (I am using chrome Version 109) ?

Comment: It's supposed to have full support in chrome, but also the examples in the MDN websites don't work...

Comment: Chrome Released 2012-06-26 Full Support :D But not now i suppose, because it is not working